# How to check if a list of dates contains today's date in Lua?

Tags: loops, search, lua

I want to write a code that automatically checks if today's date matches one of the dates in a given table. I'm not very familiar with Lua(still learning) but I do know how to use the time function howevers the platform I'm working on only support Lua 5.0 so it does not support the yday(%j) function which makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatting your date using this code:

```
-- CURRENT DATE
local myyear = os.date("*t").year
local mymonth = os.date("*t").month; if mymonth < 10 then mymonth = "0"..mymonth end
local myday = os.date("*t").day; if myday < 10 then myday = "0"..myday end
local today = myyear..mymonth..myday
print(today)
```

And then check if the date is in your table.
Hope this is not too complicated and can be of help?

PS: I am using gideros engine which uses lua.